# Cannot Eval Clojure in Lighttable

Tags: clojure

I'm learning lighttable and clojure now. but i have a problem that says permission denied when I try to eval my clojure script.

Here's the error

```
We couldn't connect.

Looks like there was an issue trying to connect to the project. Here's what we got:
final project:  {:description A local light table project, :compile-path /opt/LightTable/resources/app/plugins/Clojure/runner/resources/target/classes, :deploy-repositories [[clojars {:url https://clojars.org/repo/, :password :gpg, :username :gpg}]], :group local-client, :resource-paths (/opt/LightTable/resources/app/plugins/Clojure/runner/resources/dev-resources /opt/LightTable/resources/app/plugins/Clojure/runner/resources/resources), :uberjar-merge-with {META-INF/plexus/components.xml leiningen.uberjar/components-merger, data_readers.clj leiningen.uberjar/clj-map-merger, #"META-INF/services/.*" [clojure.core/slurp (fn* [p1__949__951__auto__ p2__950__952__auto__] (clojure.core/str p1__949__951__auto__ 
 p2__950__952__auto__)) clojure.core/spit]}, :name local-client, :checkout-deps-shares [:source-paths :test-paths :resource-paths :compile-path #'leiningen.core.classpath/checkout-deps-paths], :source-paths (/opt/LightTable/resources/app/plugins/Clojure/runner/resources/src), :eval-in :subprocess, :repositories [[central {:url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, :snapshots false}] [clojars {:url https://clojars.org/repo/}]], :test-paths (/opt/LightTable/resources/app/plugins/Clojure/runner/resources/test), :target-path /opt/LightTable/resources/app/plugins/Clojure/runner/resources/target, :prep-tasks [javac compile], :native-path /opt/LightTable/resources/app/plugins/Clojure/runner/resources/target/native, :offline? false, :root /opt/LightTable/resources/app/plugins/Clojure/runner/resources, :pedantic? ranges, :clean-targets [:target-path], :plugins [], :plugin-repositories [[central {:url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, :snapshots false}] [clojars {:url https://clojars.org/repo/}]], :version 0.0.1, :jar-exclusions [#"^\."], :global-vars {}, :uberjar-exclusions [#"(?i)^META-INF/[^/]*\.(SF|RSA|DSA)$"], :jvm-opts [], :dependencies ([org.clojure/clojure 1.5.1] [org.clojure/tools.nrepl 0.2.10 :exclusions ([org.clojure/clojure])] [clojure-complete/clojure-complete 0.2.3 :exclusions ([org.clojure/clojure])] [lein-light-nrepl/lein-light-nrepl 0.1.3] [lein-light-nrepl-instarepl/lein-light-nrepl-instarepl 0.3.1]), :release-tasks [[vcs assert-committed] [change version leiningen.release/bump-version release] [vcs commit] [vcs tag] [deploy] [change version leiningen.release/bump-version] [vcs commit] [vcs push]], :repl-options {:nrepl-middleware [lighttable.nrepl.handler/lighttable-ops], :init (clojure.core/swap! lighttable.nrepl.core/my-settings clojure.core/merge {:name LightTable-REPL, :project (quote {:description A local light table project, :compile-path /opt/LightTable/resources/app/plugins/Clojure/runner/resources/target/classes, :deploy-repositories [[clojars {:url https://clojars.org/repo/, :password :gpg, :username :gpg}]], :group local-client, :resource-paths (/opt/LightTable/resources/app/plugins/Clojure/runner/resources/dev-resources /opt/LightTable/resources/app/plugins/Clojure/runner/resources/resources), :uberjar-merge-with {META-INF/plexus/components.xml leiningen.uberjar/components-merger, data_readers.clj leiningen.uberjar/clj-map-merger, #"META-INF/services/.*" [clojure.core/slurp (fn* [p1__949__951__auto__ p2__950__952__auto__] (clojure.core/str p1__949__951__auto__ 
 p2__950__952__auto__)) clojure.core/spit]}, :name local-client, :checkout-deps-shares [:source-paths :test-paths :resource-paths :compile-path #'leiningen.core.classpath/checkout-deps-paths], :source-paths (/opt/LightTable/resources/app/plugins/Clojure/runner/resources/src), :eval-in :subprocess, :repositories [[central {:url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, :snapshots false}] [clojars {:url https://clojars.org/repo/}]], :test-paths (/opt/LightTable/resources/app/plugins/Clojure/runner/resources/test), :target-path /opt/LightTable/resources/app/plugins/Clojure/runner/resources/target, :prep-tasks [javac compile], :native-path /opt/LightTable/resources/app/plugins/Clojure/runner/resources/target/native, :offline? false, :root /opt/LightTable/resources/app/plugins/Clojure/runner/resources, :pedantic? ranges, :clean-targets [:target-path], :plugins [], :plugin-repositories [[central {:url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, :snapshots false}] [clojars {:url https://clojars.org/repo/}]], :version 0.0.1, :jar-exclusions [#"^\."], :global-vars {}, :uberjar-exclusions [#"(?i)^META-INF/[^/]*\.(SF|RSA|DSA)$"], :jvm-opts [], :dependencies ([org.clojure/clojure 1.5.1] [org.clojure/tools.nrepl 0.2.10 :exclusions ([org.clojure/clojure])] [clojure-complete/clojure-complete 0.2.3 :exclusions ([org.clojure/clojure])]), :release-tasks [[vcs assert-committed] [change version leiningen.release/bump-version release] [vcs commit] [vcs tag] [deploy] [change version leiningen.release/bump-version] [vcs commit] [vcs push]], :test-selectors {:default (constantly true)}})})}, :test-selectors {:default (constantly true)}}
java.io.IOException: Permission denied. Please check your access rights for /opt/LightTable/resources/app/plugins/Clojure/runner/resources/.nrepl-port
    at leiningen.repl$repl.doInvoke(repl.clj:317)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
    at leiningen.light_nrepl$light.invoke(light_nrepl.clj:77)
    at leiningen.light_nrepl$_main.doInvoke(light_nrepl.clj:85)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at leiningen.light_nrepl.main(Unknown Source)
```

I know it's about permission, but i don't know which folder/files should I change the permission. I already do chown in all over `plugins` folder
I'm using Lighttable IDE in Manjaro

Comment: which version of lighttable / which version of AUR/lighttable(-git) ? - also the error specificly tells you which file rises the IOException

Comment: I am using Lighttable v0.8.1, and I just install it via "yaourt -S lighttable"

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the same underlying cause, since yours doesn't seem to be on MacOS, but the same error shows up due to App Translocation.

On recent versions of MacIS there is a security feature called App Translocation that runs apps on a read-only file system (see http://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/app-translocation.html and https://objective-see.com/blog/blog_0x15.html).

The Light Table permissions error will involve the path /private/var/folders/.../AppTranslocation...

To fix this, put both LightTable.app and light in the /Applications folder. For *each* of them, go through the process for allowing unsigned apps (http://www.macworld.com/article/3094865/macs/how-to-run-apps-that-are-not-from-the-app-store-in-macos-sierra.html). Then, rather than starting LightTable.app, start light instead (this will also start a console window).

Comment: Solved my issue.  However this is a pretty terrible experience for end users.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Please check your access rights for /opt/LightTable/resources/app/plugins/Clojure/runner/resources/.nrepl-port
```

Looks like it has something to do with you clojure plug-in in LightTalbe
Highly suggest that check your LightTable's configuration

Comment: I checked it but I didn't found any files called .nrepl-port (I already show hidden files also)

Comment: @MochamadLuckyPradana `didn't found any files called .nrepl-port` well, I presume that's because the program is not able to create one due to insufficient permissions

Comment: I did `chown` to my user also @birdspider